# How to get the mean of the first and third quartile using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

This is what I did to use ascend a list by smallest to largest, then i found the median of the list.
What I need now, is to find the mean of the first quartile, and of the third one.

```
import pandas as pd

f = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
print(f.CRIM.sort_values())
print(f['CRIM'].quantile([0.5]))
```

This code sort the values and gives me the median of the list.

Comment: Can you show the sample data and your expected output ?

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/arslanali4343/real-estate-dataset?select=data.csv there is the data. I want the first list <CRIM>. The expected output, well, is the mean of the first quartile, and the mean of the third quartile.

Comment: Please try to get a sample data and can address your problem

Answer (score 1):

Using dataframe.describe() will give the quartiles as well as various other pieces of useful information (mean, min, max, etc).

Edit

Link to docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html?highlight=describe#pandas.DataFrame.describe

Comment: how to apply the mean and median on the same time?

Comment: If you're looking for a good description of the DataFrame, column by column then above is a good approach.

If you want just the mean or the median, you can call dataframe['column'].mean() or dataframe['column'].median().

I'm not sure I fully understand the question

Comment: if you take a look at my question, you will see that I know how to pull a median using quantile 0.25, 0.5, 0.75 - to get the first, second or third quantile. My question is, I want to get the MEAN of the first half of the list.

Comment: I've been checking all the different quantile options & numpy options but I still don't know the answer. I apologise.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st quartile splits off the lowest 25% of data from the highest 75%.

I am not pretty sure if there's a solution to get it instantly with a line of code but following code will make it for you.

```
data_first_quartile = f.loc[f['CRIM'] <= f['CRIM'].quantile(0.25))

print(data_first_quartile['CRIM'].mean())
```

Hope this works for you.